# Autologin to Outlook in Domain with Exchange 2016

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

I have a small LAB with AD, where one of my servers is Exchange 2016.

On any Windows AD client where I try to run Outlook for a first time autoconfig is get automatically to the point where I have to authenticate.

Auth window is gets my name: 'Name@Domain.Local' and I'm asked to write my password.

To logon successfully I have to take pickup option More Choices --> Use another account, and then write manually in user: DOMAIN\Name & pwd, and check "Remember my credentials". After that Outlook starts fine.

This is a point where its stuck on credentials:
[image: This is a point where its stuck on credentials]

My goal is set this config to complete autologin, when I start Outlook for 1st time with no ask about those credentials.

Where I need to change that? AD/AutoDiscover/IIS?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems I had 2 issues here:

1.
My login from the primary SMTP address is different than UPN [UserPrincipalName]:

- Joe.The.Tester@Domain.com - is primary SMTP Address,
- Joe@Domain.local in UPN

2. 

I don't had active one reg key responsible for 'autosetup' (Can be for example distributed by GPO). This is very good article explain that:
https://blog.matrixpost.net/zeroconfigexchange-and-zeroconfigexchangeonce/

After set it up and make test on another account where name and UPN was the same, on first start Outlook start without ask for anything and whole config is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think the AD domain logon is using Kerberos (you may verify via klist command), but since Outlook does not use the Kerberos ticket, you have to once login and save credentials in Windows Credential Manager (save password tick).
The link below explains how to use Outlook and related Client Access Services w/ Kerberos. If this is configured, you should not need to enter and save your credential.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/kerberos-auth-for-load-balanced-client-access?view=exchserver-2016